# Writing SQL query ---

Tags: sqlplus

Can somebody help to rewrite this query. I am not sure whether we can achieve this result by writing query or we have to write a procedure for this.

I need result from this query in two separate columns where `lm.listingmanagerid=bd.renterid` and `lm.listingmanagerid<>bd.renterid` in separate column.
Please help me.

I want both columns in select section (where lm.listingmanagerid=bd.renterid and  lm.listingmanagerid<>bd.renterid)

By using below query I am getting results where listingmanagerID's are matching with bookingdetails table, can I get unmatched ID's from both tables in different column 
`select bd.listingid from bookingdetails bd, listingmanager lm where lm.listingmanagerid=bd.renterid`

Below the structure for both tables

`CREATE  TABLE BOOKINGDETAILS (
  BOOKINGDETAILSID                 VARCHAR2(28) NOT NULL,
  LISTINGID                        VARCHAR2(28) NOT NULL,
  TRAVELLERPROTECTIONID            VARCHAR2(28),
  TRAVELLERID                      VARCHAR2(28) NOT NULL,
  TRAVELLERNAME                    VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  CHECKINDATE                      DATE NOT NULL,
  CHECKOUTDATE                     DATE NOT NULL,
  NOOFGUEST                        NUMBER NOT NULL,
  TERMSANDCON                      LONG RAW,
  BOOKINGSTATUS                    NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  BOOKINGDATE                      DATE NOT NULL,
  UPDATEDATE                       DATE,
  UPDATEDBY                        VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  CURRENCYCODE                     VARCHAR2(10),
  BOOKINGAMOUNT                    FLOAT,
  AOVSERVICEFEE                    FLOAT,
  AMENITYWITHFEE                   VARCHAR2(3000),
  OCA                              NUMBER NOT NULL,
  RENTALTOTALAMOUNT                FLOAT,
  AMENITIESFEE                     FLOAT,
  RENTERID                         VARCHAR2(28),
  CANCELLATIONAMOUNT               FLOAT,
  PAYMENTID                        VARCHAR2(28),
  CCNUMBER                         VARCHAR2(30),
  LISTINGMANAGERID                 VARCHAR2(28),
  OWNERVIEWSTATUS                  NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 0,
  OWNERVIEWSTATUSDATE              DATE,
  BOOKINGSTATUSDATE                DATE,
  OWNERPAYOUTSTATUS                NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 0,
  OWNERPAYOUTSTATUSDATE            DATE,
  DISPUTESTATUS                    NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 0,
  DISPUTESTATUSDATE                DATE,
  TRAVELLERPAYMENTSTATUS           NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 0,
  TRAVELLERPAYMENTSTATUSDATE       DATE,
  REJECTIONREASON                  NUMBER(10),
  REJECTIONREASONDETAIL            VARCHAR2(200),
  CONSTRAINT SYS_C004345
    PRIMARY KEY ( BOOKINGDETAILSID ) 
);`

`CREATE  TABLE LISTINGMANAGER (
  LISTINGMANAGERID                 VARCHAR2(28) NOT NULL,
  FIRSTNAME                        VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  LASTNAME                         VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARYPHONE                     VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  ALTERNATEPHONE                   VARCHAR2(20),
  EMAIL                            VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  USERNAME                         VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD                         VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  RECALLGUID                       VARCHAR2(32),
  CUSTOMERSINCE                    DATE,
  LASTUPDATED                      DATE NOT NULL,
  UPDATEDBY                        VARCHAR2(28) NOT NULL,
  OCA                              NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PWCHANGEREQUIRED                 VARCHAR2(1),
  PWEXPIREDATE                     DATE,
  LASTLOGIN                        DATE,
  CALLINGHOURS                     VARCHAR2(200),
  TIMEZONEID                       VARCHAR2(20),
  CREATEDATE                       DATE,
  CREATEIPADDRESS                  VARCHAR2(16),
  AUTORENEWFLAG                    VARCHAR2(1),
  AUTORENEWREMOVEDDATE             DATE,
  AUTORENEWDATE                    DATE,
  ISSUPPLIER                       VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PREFFEREDLANGUAGE                VARCHAR2(2),
  LOCALEID                         VARCHAR2(2),
  ADDRESS1                         VARCHAR2(50),
  ADDRESS2                         VARCHAR2(50),
  CITYID                           VARCHAR2(28),
  COUNTRYID                        VARCHAR2(28),
  STATEPROVINCEID                  VARCHAR2(28),
  POSTALCODE                       VARCHAR2(10),
  REGISTRATIONSOURCE               VARCHAR2(1),
  PPCTYPEID                        VARCHAR2(28),
  ABOUTME                          VARCHAR2(2000),
  PICTUREFILEPATH                  VARCHAR2(200),
  ISPROFILEPICTUREDISPLAY          VARCHAR2(1),
  GHOSTUSER                        VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PROFILEID                        VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT SYS_C005739
    PRIMARY KEY ( LISTINGMANAGERID ) ,
  CONSTRAINT USERNAME_CONSTRAINT
    UNIQUE(USERNAME)
);`

Thanks

Comment: Please reformulate your question so it is actually a question, and all required data (table layouts etc.) is included.

Comment: could you elaborate your question?

Comment: Please add some more details (edit your question), like sample input data en required output.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT bookingdetails.listingid AS owner from bookingdetails INNER JOIN listingmanager ON  listingmanager.listingmanagerid = bookingdetails.renterid
```

May be, you need this.